# How can we use Provider with Future?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-dependencies, flutter-provider, riverpod

I'm trying to use MultiProvider with FutureBuilder.

Is there source code that uses Firestore with Riverpod or any package to create a cart?

Also, how can we use Riverpod and Cart along with Firestore?

```js
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  MyApp({super.key});
  // List<CartModel> cartModels = new List<CartModel>.empty(growable: true);
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Firebase.initializeApp(
      options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
    );

    return MaterialApp.router(
      routerConfig: _router,
    );
  }
}

class MainPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: Firebase.initializeApp(
        options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
      ),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
          case ConnectionState.done:
            final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
            devtools.log(user.toString());
            if (user != null) {
              if (user.emailVerified) {
                devtools.log("verified");
                return const HomePage();
              } else {
                devtools.log("not verified!");
                return const Login();
              }
            } else {
              return const Login();
            }
          default:
            return const CircularProgressIndicator();
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Using MultiProvider is convenient when providing multiple objects.
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        // In this sample app, CatalogModel never changes, so a simple Provider
        // is sufficient.
        Provider(create: (context) => CatalogModel()),
        // CartModel is implemented as a ChangeNotifier, which calls for the use
        // of ChangeNotifierProvider. Moreover, CartModel depends
        // on CatalogModel, so a ProxyProvider is needed.
        ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<CatalogModel, CartModel>(
          create: (context) => CartModel(),
          update: (context, catalog, cart) {
            if (cart == null) throw ArgumentError.notNull('cart');
            cart.catalog = catalog;
            return cart;
          },
        ),
      ],
      child: const MaterialApp(
        home: MyCatalog(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyCatalog extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyCatalog({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: [
          _MyAppBar(),
          const SliverToBoxAdapter(child: SizedBox(height: 12)),
          SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                (context, index) => _MyListItem(index)),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _AddButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final Item item;

  const _AddButton({required this.item});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // The context.select() method will let you listen to changes to
    // a *part* of a model. You define a function that "selects" (i.e. returns)
    // the part you're interested in, and the provider package will not rebuild
    // this widget unless that particular part of the model changes.
    //
    // This can lead to significant performance improvements.
    var isInCart = context.select<CartModel, bool>(
      // Here, we are only interested whether [item] is inside the cart.
      (cart) => cart.items.contains(item),
    );

    return TextButton(
      onPressed: isInCart
          ? null
          : () {
              // If the item is not in cart, we let the user add it.
              // We are using context.read() here because the callback
              // is executed whenever the user taps the button. In other
              // words, it is executed outside the build method.
              var cart = context.read<CartModel>();
              cart.add(item);
            },
      style: ButtonStyle(
        overlayColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color?>((states) {
          if (states.contains(MaterialState.pressed)) {
            return Theme.of(context).primaryColor;
          }
          return null; // Defer to the widget's default.
        }),
      ),
      child: isInCart
          ? const Icon(Icons.check, semanticLabel: 'ADDED')
          : const Text('ADD'),
    );
  }
}

class _MyAppBar extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SliverAppBar(
      title: Text('Catalog', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.displayLarge),
      floating: true,
      actions: [
        IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.shopping_cart),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const MyCart()),
            );
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class _MyListItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final int index;

  const _MyListItem(this.index);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var item = context.select<CatalogModel, Item>(
      // Here, we are only interested in the item at [index]. We don't care
      // about any other change.
      (catalog) => catalog.getByPosition(index),
    );
    var textTheme = Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleLarge;

    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16, vertical: 8),
      child: LimitedBox(
        maxHeight: 48,
        child: Row(
          children: [
            AspectRatio(
              aspectRatio: 1,
              child: Container(
                color: item.color,
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(width: 24),
            Expanded(
              child: Text(item.name, style: textTheme),
            ),
            const SizedBox(width: 24),
            _AddButton(item: item),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyCart extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyCart({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Cart', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.displayLarge),
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      ),
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.yellow,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32),
                child: _CartList(),
              ),
            ),
            const Divider(height: 4, color: Colors.black),
            _CartTotal()
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _CartList extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var itemNameStyle = Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleLarge;
    // This gets the current state of CartModel and also tells Flutter
    // to rebuild this widget when CartModel notifies listeners (in other words,
    // when it changes).
    var cart = context.watch<CartModel>();

    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: cart.items.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
        leading: const Icon(Icons.done),
        trailing: IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.remove_circle_outline),
          onPressed: () {
            cart.remove(cart.items[index]);
          },
        ),
        title: Text(
          cart.items[index].name,
          style: itemNameStyle,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _CartTotal extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var hugeStyle =
        Theme.of(context).textTheme.displayLarge!.copyWith(fontSize: 48);

    return SizedBox(
      height: 200,
      child: Center(
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            // Another way to listen to a model's change is to include
            // the Consumer widget. This widget will automatically listen
            // to CartModel and rerun its builder on every change.
            //
            // The important thing is that it will not rebuild
            // the rest of the widgets in this build method.
            Consumer<CartModel>(
                builder: (context, cart, child) =>
                    Text('\$${cart.totalPrice}', style: hugeStyle)),
            const SizedBox(width: 24),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                    const SnackBar(content: Text('Buying not supported yet.')));
              },
              style: TextButton.styleFrom(foregroundColor: Colors.white),
              child: const Text('BUY'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CartModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  /// The private field backing [catalog].
  late CatalogModel _catalog;

  /// Internal, private state of the cart. Stores the ids of each item.
  final List<int> _itemIds = [];

  /// The current catalog. Used to construct items from numeric ids.
  CatalogModel get catalog => _catalog;

  set catalog(CatalogModel newCatalog) {
    _catalog = newCatalog;
    // Notify listeners, in case the new catalog provides information
    // different from the previous one. For example, availability of an item
    // might have changed.
    notifyListeners();
  }

  /// List of items in the cart.
  List<Item> get items => _itemIds.map((id) => _catalog.getById(id)).toList();

  /// The current total price of all items.
  int get totalPrice =>
      items.fold(0, (total, current) => total + current.price);

  /// Adds [item] to cart. This is the only way to modify the cart from outside.
  void add(Item item) {
    _itemIds.add(item.id);
    // This line tells [Model] that it should rebuild the widgets that
    // depend on it.
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void remove(Item item) {
    _itemIds.remove(item.id);
    // Don't forget to tell dependent widgets to rebuild _every time_
    // you change the model.
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class CatalogModel {
  static List<String> itemNames = [
    'Code Smell',
    'Control Flow',
    'Interpreter',
    'Recursion',
    'Sprint',
    'Heisenbug',
    'Spaghetti',
    'Hydra Code',
    'Off-By-One',
    'Scope',
    'Callback',
    'Closure',
    'Automata',
    'Bit Shift',
    'Currying',
  ];

  /// Get item by [id].
  ///
  /// In this sample, the catalog is infinite, looping over [itemNames].
  Item getById(int id) => Item(id, itemNames[id % itemNames.length]);

  /// Get item by its position in the catalog.
  Item getByPosition(int position) {
    // In this simplified case, an item's position in the catalog
    // is also its id.
    return getById(position);
  }
}

@immutable
class Item {
  final int id;
  final String name;
  final Color color;
  final int price = 42;

  Item(this.id, this.name)
      // To make the sample app look nicer, each item is given one of the
      // Material Design primary colors.
      : color = Colors.primaries[id % Colors.primaries.length];

  @override
  int get hashCode => id;

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) => other is Item && other.id == id;
}
```

Here is a complete example with Flutter that you can test.

Comment: u are amazing man , do you know how can i use it with firestore btw, or how the process gonna happen ? btw did u use riverpod or just provider ? why havn't u used riverpod

Comment: check this demo https://github.com/ishworpanta10/ecommerce_demo